# How can I make contribution to MiKTeX via localizing (I mean, translating the GUI page)?

Tags: miktex

I want to translate the MiKTeX GUI page, and where can I do this?
I did not find anywhere to contribute by translation.
(Maybe I can advise the MiKTeX manager to give such a place.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translation procedure is described in this article:
https://miktex.org/howto/l10n

In short:

1. if this is a new language (e.g., "French"): submit an issue: "add new language: fr"
2. use Git to get the source code
3. edit .ts files (Qt Linguist)
4. edit .po files (GNU gettext utilities)
5. push your changes and create a GitHub pull request